# Right way to delete pointer to pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, double-pointer

I have this simple example which fails in "delete poinerToBufferPointer":

```
char* buffer = new char[8];
memset(buffer, 1, 8);
char** poinerToBufferPointer = &buffer;
delete poinerToBufferPointer;
delete[] buffer;
```

But if I comment the "delete poinerToBufferPointer"

```
char* buffer = new char[8];
memset(buffer, 1, 8);
char** poinerToBufferPointer = &buffer;
//delete poinerToBufferPointer;
delete[] buffer;
```

it's working but the question is who will delete the double pointer?
Also very strange behavior is when I do delete on the pointer only it fail on `delete[]` buffer.

```
char* buffer = new char[8];
memset(buffer, 1, 8);
char** poinerToBufferPointer = &buffer;
delete *poinerToBufferPointer;  // <--- only delete the pointer that points 
delete[] buffer;
```

What is going on in memory, and what is the right way to delete both pointers?

Comment: Why do you think you need to `delete` the pointer? Your second code snippet is correct.

Comment: The right way in C++ is to avoid this all together (avoid [new/delete](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly) & avoid owning raw pointers). Learn how to use `std::vector<char>` and/or `std::string` first. (even memset is hardly ever needed)

Comment: It might be you are learning C++ from an outdated source. Good sources to learn cpp from are : [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). A [recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or have a go at https://www.learncpp.com/ (that's pretty decent, and pretty up-to-date).
When you've mastered the C++ basics from those sources, look at the [C++ coreguidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) regularely to keep up-to-date.

Comment: You should `delete` something once, and if and only if it was `new`ed. In this case `poinerToBufferPointer` is assigned an address of existing data and is not `new`ed. And in the last snippet `*poinerToBufferPointer` is equal to buffer so `delete[] buffer` attempts to delete it a second time (which is invalid).

Comment: Adding a note to wohlstad's, `delete *poinerToBufferPointer` should not be working either. Since `*poinerToBufferPointer` is equal to `buffer` and `buffer` was allocated using `new[]`, it must be deleted using `delete[]`. Using `delete` in this case would be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You do not `delete` pointers, you `delete` the thing a pointer points to.
2. You only need to `delete` things you allocate with `new`

`delete[] buffer;` deletes the array pointed to by the pointer `buffer`.  Since you allocated that with `new[]` that is correct.

`delete pointerToBufferPointer;` attempts to delete the pointer pointed to by `pointerToBufferPointer`.  You did not allocate that pointer using `new`, however, so that is incorrect.  A program that attempts to do that has undefined behavior.

If you had allocated the pointer pointed to by `pointerToBufferPointer` using `new` then you would need to `delete` it.  For example, the following is correct (though you should almost never need to write code like this):

```
char** pointerToBufferPointer = new char*;
*pointerToBufferPointer = new char[8];
// ...
delete[] *pointerToBufferPointer;
delete pointerToBufferPOinter;
```

---

In most real code you should avoid using `new` and `delete` directly at all.  For most common use cases, containers like `std::string` and `std::vector` that manage their own memory allocation for you are perfectly sufficient and much less error-prone.

Comment: Nice clear explanation for newbies. pointers and `delete` `new` can be confusing at first.